# Global Dashboard Configuration

Tags: dashboard

Is there any way to change the default configuration for the Dashboard globally, or per user group?

I don't mind `Sysadmins` seeing the *Blog & Tonic* feed, but I don't want `Members` (who access the CP only to add calendar events) to see *Blog & Tonic*. It will just cause confusion for those users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [One Dashboard](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/onedashboard) which works nicely. I've used it to set each users Dashboard to show a collection of pre-defined Analytics widgets.

Comment: The way I interpret the description of _One Dashboard_ is that it would only help me with new users. It doesn't sound like it would affect existing users.

Comment: I can verify that it will effect existing users as well. The next time a user visits their Dashboard, it'll populate with the pre-defined widgets.

Comment: I confirmed with the developer of _One Dashboard_ that the current version works only on first login. It does not update on subsequent logins.

Comment: @PhilipJones have a look at https://github.com/james1238/duplicateuserdashboard/

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no native way to do this in Craft, although it's probably worth an addition to the [feedback site](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com).